# refer to ModelField property in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

There is a possibility in Django templates to refer to attributes of the field directly in a template. For example to .help_text or .label. Like that:

```
 {% for field in form %}
    {{field.label|safe}}
    {{field}}
 {% endfor %}
```

**What is the right way to refer to a custom defined field property?**
For example:

```
  {{field.myproperty}}
```

I use ModelForm and in models.py I use my own ModelField. Everything works perfectly but any attempts to add my own property fail. In a sense that everything is ok but if I refer to this property in a template it just doesn't get it :-(

**Models.py:**

```
        class MyFormField(forms.IntegerField):
            MyProperty = 'whatever'
            def __init__(self,active1='default',*args, **kwargs):
                self.MyProperty = 'whatever'
                super(MyFormField, self).__init__(*args,  **kwargs)


        class MyOwnField(models.IntegerField):
            def __init__(self, active1='asdf',*args, **kwargs):
                super(MyOwnField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


            def formfield(self, **kwargs):
                defaults = {'form_class': MyFormField}
                defaults.update(kwargs)
                return super().formfield(**defaults)

        class MyModel(Model):
              ns6_1 = MyOwnField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, case is significant; `field.myproperty` is not the same as `field.MyProperty`.

Secondly, when you iterate through a form you don't directly get the form fields, you get BoundField instances. Each of these has a `field` property which is the field itself. So:

```
{{ field.field.MyProperty }}
```